# What's more common? "You've got bad taste", "you've got a bad taste," or "you've got bad tastes."

Tags: expressions, idioms

What's the most common expression? (More specifically in the US?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what each means:

### You've got bad taste

This is the norm.  It means somebody's idea of what is good is actually not.  If a person paired a green tie with yellow pants, you might say they have *bad taste*.

### You've got a bad taste

You have either just physically tasted somebody and found them repulsive, or something is a little bit *off* about the person that leaves you with a "bad taste."  A more natural way to say this is to say the person is [shady](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shady).

### You've got bad tastes

Similar to the first example, except I would expect to see this in a plural setting.  The person referred to here must have a multitude of "bad tastes."  This is not a common idiom.